# Update operator yields empty object in JQ

Tags: jq

I cannot understand the behaviour of the update operator of jq (version 1.6) shown in the following examples.

Why does example 1 return an updated object, but example 2 and 3 return an empty object or a wrong result?

The difference between the examples is only the calling order of the function to convert a string into a number.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# strange behaviour jq

# example 1 - works as expected
jq -n '
  def numberify($x): $x | tonumber? // 0;

  "1" as $stringValue
  | numberify($stringValue) as $intValue
# | { }                                     # version 1: a.b does not exist yet
  | { a: { b: 1 } }                         # version 2: a.b exists already
  | .["a"] |= { b: (.b + $intValue) }
'
# result example 1, version 1 - expected
#   {
#     "a": {
#       "b": 1
#     }
#   }

# result example 1, version 2 - expected
#   {
#     "a": {
#       "b": 2
#     }
#   }


# example 2 - erroneous result
jq -n '
  def numberify($x): $x | tonumber? // 0;

  "1" as $stringValue
# | { }                           # version 1: a.b does not exist yet
  | { a: { b: 1 } }               # version 2: a.b exists already
  | .["a"] |= { b: (.b + numberify($stringValue)) }
'
# result example 2, version 1 - unexpected
#   {}

# result example 2, version 2 - unexpected
#   {}


# example 3 - erroneous result
jq -n '
  def numberify($x): $x | try tonumber catch 0;

  "1" as $stringValue
# | { }                           # version 1: a.b does not exist yet
  | { a: { b: 1 } }               # version 2: a.b exists already
  | .["a"] |= { b: (.b + numberify($stringValue)) }
'
# result example 3, version 1 - unexpected
#   {
#     "a": {
#       "b": 0
#     }
#   }

# result example 3, version 2 - unexpected
#   {
#     "a": {
#       "b": 1
#     }
#   }
```

---

@oguzismail That's a good idea to use '+=' instead of '|='.
I hadn't thought of it before.
Currently, my code with the workaround for the bug looks like this:

```
  def numberify($x): $x | tonumber? // 0;

  "1" as $sumReqSize
  | "10" as $sumResSize
  | { statistics: { count: 1, sumReqSize: 2, sumResSize: 20 } }
  | [numberify($sumReqSize), numberify($sumResSize)] as $sizes     # workaround for bug
  | .statistics |= {
                     count: (.count + 1),
                     sumReqSize: (.sumReqSize + $sizes[0]),
                     sumResSize: (.sumResSize + $sizes[1])
                   }
'
```

Following your suggestion it will be more concise and doesn't need the ugly workaround:

```
  def numberify($x): $x | tonumber? // 0;

  "1" as $sumReqSize
  | "10" as $sumResSize
  | { statistics: { count: 1, sumReqSize: 2, sumResSize: 20 } }
  | .statistics.count += 1
  | .statistics.sumReqSize += numberify($sumReqSize)
  | .statistics.sumResSize += numberify($sumResSize)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in jq 1.6.  One option would be to use an earlier version of jq (e.g. jq 1.5).

Another would be to avoid `|=` by using `=` instead, along the lines of:

```
.a = (.a | ...)
```

or if the RHS does not actually depend on the LHS (as in your original examples), simply replacing `|=` by `=`.

Comment: This is a clever trick to bypass the buggy update operator in this case - it works!

Answer (score 3):

This is [a bug](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2140) in jq 1.6. In this case you can use try-catch instead.

```
def numberify($x): $x | try tonumber catch 0;
```

But I don't know if there is a generic way to walk around this issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. After I modified the original question so that the update operator makes sense, the solution you suggested no longer helps. I added one more example with the use of 'try catch' instead of '? //'

Comment: very helpful that you have added a link to the corresponding jq issue

Comment: @jpseng - The try/catch solution should work using the current "master" version of jq (i.e. jq > 1.6).

Comment: @jpseng it seems very similar to the bug I linked. I don't know of a general workaround for this. We can provide case-specific workarounds of course (like `.["a"].b += numberify(...`), but I guess it's not what you're looking for.

Comment: @oguzismail - Please see my updated response regarding rewriting `|=`.

Comment: @oguzismail Good idea to use '+=' instead of '|=' for my use case

Comment: @peak Good to know, thanks! Unfortunately, can't upvote twice